# Recursion Relation - Solution

Tags: recursion

> Consider the relation $$p_x + p_{x-1}p_{x} = p_{x-1}$$ with $p_1$ given.

The solution is written $$\frac{1}{p_x} = \frac{1}{p_1} + (x-1)$$ in my lecture notes as though trivial.

I can't seem to get it.

I have tried to re-arrange the main expression for $\frac{1}{p_x} = 1 + \frac{1}{p_{x-1}}$, but I am not sure how to finish this off.

Any hint is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac1{p_x}=\dfrac1{p_{x-1}}+1=\dfrac1{p_{x-2}}+2=\cdots=\dfrac1{p_1}+(x-1)$

Comment: omg of course, so trivial!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Notice that sequence $a_x =\frac{1}{p_x}$ is arithmetic with difference $1$. So $$a_x = a_1+(x-1)\cdot 1$$
and thus a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

From

$$
p_k+p_kp_{k-1}-p_{k-1}=0\Rightarrow \frac{1}{p_{k-1}}+1-\frac{1}{p_k} = 0
$$

now calling $q_k = \frac{1}{p_k}$ we have

$$
q_{k-1} + 1 - q_{k} = 0
$$

with solution

$$
q_k = k+C_0
$$

hence

$$
p_k = \frac{1}{k+C_0}
$$

Comment: in the first line, did you mean $\dfrac {p_k}{p_{k-1}}+\color{red}p_k-\dfrac{p_{k-1}}{p_k}=0$?

Comment: Thanks to your comment I was able to find an error now corrected.